Do genitive case Possessivpronomina exist for Masculine and Neuter singular possessa?
I know Possessivartikel exist in the genitive for Masculine and Neuter singular possessa.
For instance:
(Neutrum Possessum)

Ich bin allein und freue mich meines Lebens in dieser Gegend, die für solche Seelen geschaffen ist wie die meine." — Werther, Goethe

(Masc Possessum)

Die Qualität meines Tisches ist gut.

I also know Possessivpronomina exist in the genitive for feminine and plural possessa, and that they are the same as the Possessivaritkel in the same case for the same possessa. E.g. "meiner".
But I have heard that use of "meines" as a pronoun in the genitive is incorrect? So what would be used in its place in formal writing, where dative constructions with "von" are not ideal?

Welcome to German SE! Please explain, what is left unclear after a look into a dictionary/grammar book, as wiktionary, since the question might be closed otherwise. What you have heard might be simply wrong.

Some examples: Löffel sind meist billig, aber die Herstellung meines war teuer. Gabeln sind meist billig, aber die Herstellung meiner war teuer. (taken from https://german.stackexchange.com/a/70699) These are constructed examples; speakers would probably indeed not use the possessive pronoun here.

The usage of a masculine or neuter possessive pronoun as in your examples is perfectly correct, but just extremely rarely used (probably because some of these genitive forms are identical with nominative ones for masculine and neuter and might lead to confusion).

Ich bin mir meines Fehlers bewusst, du dir deines offensichtlich nicht.

To work around this, native speakers will likely use some substantive, article or adjective to extend the pronoun (just to have something to put the genitive mark on), like in

Löffel sind meist billig, aber die Herstellung meines Exemplars war teuer.


Löffel sind meist billig, aber die Herstellung meines silbernen war teuer.


Löffel sind meist billig, aber die Herstellung des meinen war teuer [that sounds weird]


Was wäre ein Beispiel, in dem eine Konfusion auftreten könnte?

I would typically extend this not by a substantive, but by an article, say "des deinigen".

@TilmanSchmidt Well, the extension can basically be anything that can hold the genitive mark.

Possessives exist as determiners, adjectives, and pronouns:

i) in unserer gegenwärtigen Welt
ii) in der unseren, uns(e)rigen (gegenwärtigen Welt)
iii) (in seiner Welt, aber nicht) in unserer

Note that the adjective is only rarely followed by a noun.
In my observation, the genitive of the pronoun is indeed avoided; especially since the adjective is available.

Trennt er sich von ihm oder läßt er sich von ihm trennen durch Schwachheit oder falschen Rat, so löst er sich von seinem Schwur und entbindet mich des meinen. (Fontane, https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/fontane/vorsturm/vors213.html)
Aus dieser Zeit, also etwa aus meinem vierten oder fünften Lebensjahr, erinnere ich mich als meines ersten Spielgenossen eines kleinen Grafen Kalman, dessen Vater ein Patient des meinen war. (Schnitzler, https://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Schnitzler,+Arthur/Autobiographisches/Jugend+in+Wien/Erstes+Buch)
Paul Kreidl brachte mir gestern abend ein Paar Schuhe, die mir genau passen und bei dem furchtbaren Zustand der meinigen höchst willkommen sind. (Klemperer, https://www.bpb.de/shop/zeitschriften/izpb/nationalsozialismus-krieg-und-holocaust-316/151942/massenmord-und-holocaust/)

